# JSObjectionScopeSingleton is partially broken in Objection framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection

AppModule:

```
[self bindBlock:^id(JSObjectionInjector *context) {

return [[SystemDataRepository alloc] initWithAppComponent:context];

    } toProtocol:@protocol(SystemRepository) inScope:JSObjectionScopeSingleton];
```

Creation of user module:

```
JSObjectionInjector *userComponent = [appComponent withModule:[[UserModule alloc] initWithUserId:userId]];
```

With no regard to JSObjectionScopeSingleton declaration in the app module, the user module creates it's own objects of the same definition.

Comment: which cocoapods version you are using?

Comment: recent 1.6.1 installed from Cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in below thread, it was issue in cocoapods 1.6.

thread tells that it fixed now in cocoapds 1.6.1 release:

https://github.com/atomicobject/objection/releases/tag/1.6.1

check the thread below for reference:

[inScope:JSObjectionScopeSingleton doesn't work since Cocoapods version 1.6](https://github.com/atomicobject/objection/issues/94)

Answer (score 0):

As discovered **withModule** method always creates copy of an injector.

To avoid such behavior it's required to create another module as standalone:

```
[JSObjection createInjector:[[UserModule alloc] init]]
```

But in this case this module will not have access to other modules bindings.

Fortunately, the framework have the global context to keep bindings of all modules.
Unfortunately, this feature is broken in 1.6.1

I've created fixed version here: https://github.com/AlexeyPoldeo/objection/tree/develop/Source

Also, I've created a pull request to the original repository.